# Loading packages installed from a local .zip file

Tags: r, package, loading

I am trying to load a self-written package in order to use the functions I created there without having to copy and paste them into each new project. The program is having difficulties to recognize the package though. These are the lines I am inputting and the messages issued by the system.

```
> .libPaths(c(.libPaths(), "path-to-package"))
> install.packages("somepath/myPackage.zip", repos = NULL, lib = "path-to-package")
> library("myPackage", lib.loc = "path-to-package")
Error in library("myPackage", lib.loc = "path-to-package") : 
  ‘myPackage’ ist keine gültiges installiertes Paket
```

After issuing "install.packages", new directories and files are displayed in Microsoft Explorer. While other files vanish at the end, the directory named "myPackage" remains.

Would it be easier to try and get R do my bidding and make it recognize myPackage as a package not only when installnig, but also when loading it? Or is it easier to copy and paste the functions from the package when I need them?

I do own the book "R Packages" by Hadley Wickham in its first edition from 2015. Are there any passages I might want to reread to get going?

Comment: How did you build myPackage?

Comment: By pressing Ctrl-Shift-e.

Comment: That runs R CMD check. You should go to to the *Build* panel in RStudio. In its menu chose *More*  -> *Build Binary Package*  (or *Build Source Package* if you want to install from source).